# Adding search server to existing SharePoint 2013 farm

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, server-farm

I want to add one Dedicated search server with Dedicated search roles to our current SharePoint 2013 farm, could you please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending in your requirements and how many servers in your farm, you can create a Search Service Application in Central Admin or through PowerShell. Since you mention you want a dedicated server you will probably have to use PowerShell for provisioning.

I don't know your requirements for the 6 components of the SSA but this should help with the initial topology: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/19/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thank you but I've already have search service configured in one of our web application server. and our farm are not similar to this blog.

Comment: OK, I am confused then, your question is asking how to add a search server. That is what I answered.

Comment: Yes,Thank you but it says :"Very important: if your environment doesn’t look like this, STOP here.

If you already have Search Configured, which would be your default setting if you have run the Farm Configuration Wizard, don’t use this script."  I have configured my search but now I want to run it on a new dedicated server

Comment: You need to clone the existing active topology and then move the 6 components to where you want them in the clone. Once you have done that, activate the clone. After activation you can delete the old inactive topology.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: no this is our November task.